# Why my BMP image is bigger than the original after reducing its width and height?

Tags: c#, image

In my project, i have to resize the image and then save it to a folder. However, i got a problem which some image will be bigger than the orginal's file size.

**resize method:**

```
    public Image reduce(Image sourceImage, string size)
    {
        double percent = Convert.ToDouble(size) / 100;
        int width = (int)(sourceImage.Width * percent);
        int height = (int)(sourceImage.Height *percent );
        var resized = new Bitmap(original, width, height);
        return resized;
    }
```

using:

```
//the code to get the image is omitted (in my testing, bmp format is fixed, however, other image formats are required)
//to test the size of original image
oImage.Save(Path.Combine(oImagepath), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);

Image nImage = resizeClass.reduce(oImage,"95");
nImage.Save(Path.Combine(nImagepath), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

Result:

> - The first saving of the image:  1920*1080, fileSize: **6076KB**
> - The second saving of the image:  1824*1026, fileSize: **7311KB** <= it should be less than 6076KB

Image:

- [original](https://1drv.ms/i/s!AsdOBLg50clihVckCg_h89rsZZCG)
- [resized](https://1drv.ms/i/s!AsdOBLg50clihViS4FptecStVSMN)

**Update**

The Bit depth of original image is 24 which resized is 32. Is the problem here?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you are saving it as BMP?

Comment: @Euphoric, yes! you may check the image url above! It is XXXX.bmp image

Comment: Maybe original image is 16 bpp and output is 24 bpp?

Comment: @i486 OOOOOOOH, the bit depth of the original is 24 and resized is 32!!!!!!! However, how to fix it???

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.encoder.colordepth%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @kurakura88 by the link you provided, it seem to control the ColorDepth by using `myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 24L);` However, i have to check the colorDepth of the original first, right? So, how to check the image colour depth in code?

Comment: The difference in size is definitely the pixelformat difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your provided Code, i've made an ExtensionMethod you might want to use:

```
public static class ImageExtensions {

    public static System.Drawing.Image Reduce(this System.Drawing.Image sourceImage, double size) {
      var percent = size / 100;
      var width = (int)(sourceImage.Width * percent);
      var height = (int)(sourceImage.Height * percent);         
      Bitmap targetBmp;
      using (var newBmp = new Bitmap(sourceImage, width, height))
        targetBmp = newBmp.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), sourceImage.PixelFormat);
      return targetBmp;
    }

  }
```

**Usage**

```
 var nImage = new Bitmap(@"PathToImage").Reduce(50); //Percentage here
 nImage.Save(@"PathToNewImage", ImageFormat.Jpeg); //Change Compression as you need
```

Please note, that this is now automaticly determinating, where the new Image has its x = 0 and y = 0. Also i've replaced the string-percentage with a double one.

As others in the comments mentioned, you have to use the same or even lower `PixelFormat` as the SourceImage. Also, setting the right/best image-extension on the Save-Method reduces the FileSize

Hope this helps

Comment: why it is not zero of destX and destY?

Comment: You are kinda right, first method extracted the image proportional. Updated answer

Comment: Since I've modified my answer, it should not any longer

Answer (score 1):

The color depth is increasing your filesize.

There might be a better way but you can just convert you generated 32 bit bitmap to a 24 bit one

```
Bitmap clone = new Bitmap(resized.Width, resized.Height,
    System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(clone)) {
    gr.DrawImage(resized, new Rectangle(0, 0, clone.Width, clone.Height));
}
```

Comment: I have to check the original image depth before i increasing it because the original image may be 32 bit depth. (i cannot convert the image to 24 bit if it is 32 bit)

Comment: can`t you just use the *image.PixelFormat* see here, it should give you exactly that information
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat.aspx